# Change CSS stylesheet with transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar, a footer, some content boxes and an image that I want to change on the flick of a switch. I think effectively I want to swap style sheets on a button click.

I know I can change elements using JavaScript like so

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">
    Change the image
</button>
```

But there's a couple of issues I get with this already

1. It doesn't have a fading transition
2. This won't persist through my pages

So basically the user should be able to choose between a light theme and a dark theme **throughout the site** and when swapping, the transition on the elements should fade over e.g. 1 second.

The best approach I could think of so far was to do the javascript to transition while loading the 2nd sheet in (so JS handles the on-page transition and when a new page loads a different CSS file is in place)

But I wondered if anyone out there had a better solution?

Comment: Why not add a class to the `body` tag and then store that information in the session? There is no need for two style sheets.

Comment: You mean the body selector in the CSS file? Forgive me, I'm not very good at CSS I've only done basic stuff.

Comment: You need to add it to the HTML and the CSS. You basically use JS to add a class to the DOM body tag (e.g. `dark`) and then in your CSS you change your styles `body { styles for initial "light" state }` or `body.dark { styles for "dark" state }`. Since the switching happens based on class, your transitions will fire when you change.